# replace mysql_num_rows($result); with $result->num_rows;

Tags: notepad++, regex, wildcards

I am in the process of changing old `mysql` code with `mysqli`. I am using notepad++ to do this since it is much faster than using dreamweaver IMO.

I need a regex find and replace that would do this for me. The reason is `$result` can vary in the name. It could be

```
$result
$result_blah
$result_blah_blah
```

So I need to go from `mysql_num_rows($result);` to `$result->num_rows;` keeping in mind the variable name could be different.

Anyone have a regex than can do this?

**SOLVED**

Sorry asked to soon, I figured it out. It was a matter of using capture with `()`

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

```
Find: mysql_num_rows\((.+)\)
Replace: \1->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: Great you've solved it! It's absolutely fine to answer your own questions here, please post your solution as an answer instead of editing it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I need to go from `mysql_num_rows($result);` to `$result->num_rows;`

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `mysql_num_rows\((\$result.*)\)`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1->num_rows`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Disable "matches newline"

[image]

**Example before**:

```
blah blah blah
mysql_num_rows($foo);
mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_num_rows($result_blah);
mysql_num_rows($result_blah_blah);
mysql_num_rows($bar);
blah blah blah
```

**Example after**:

```
blah blah blah
mysql_num_rows($foo);
$result->num_rows;
$result_blah->num_rows;
$result_blah_blah->num_rows;
mysql_num_rows($bar);
blah blah blah
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)